# How to output JSON from Slick query result?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, slick

I'm a newbie when it comes to Scala and right now trying to learn Slick. I have a database set up much like in the Slick tutorial and querying it with

```
val users:TableQuery[user] = TableQuery[user]
```

How do I output users -value in to JSON from Play framework? I have tried defining case class for user and making reader+writer for userFormat = Json.format[user] but I have no clue where I'm going wrong or anything. I've done similar kind of stuff with Spray.IO and it seemed simple and straightforward there, but I want to learn how to do it with Play and Slick and I am completely lost :(

Here is my Tables.scala:

```
    package assets

    import org.joda.time.DateTime
    import play.api.libs.json._
    import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
    import com.github.tototoshi.slick.MySQLJodaSupport._
    import scala.slick.lifted.{ProvenShape}

    case class user
      (
      id:Int,
      textId:String,
      sessionId:String,
      stamp:DateTime
    )

    class users(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, DateTime)](tag, "USER") {

      implicit object userFormat extends Format[user] {

        def writes(a: user): JsValue = {
          Json.obj(
            "id" -> JsNumber(a.id),
            "textId" -> JsString(a.textId),
            "sessionId" -> JsString(a.sessionId),
            "stamp" -> JsString(a.stamp.toString())
          )
        }

        def reads(json: JsValue): user = user(
          (json \ "id").as[Int],
          (json \ "textId").as[String],
          (json \ "sessionId").as[String],
          (json \ "stamp").as[DateTime]
        )
      }

      def id: Column[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
      def textId: Column[String] = column[String]("textId")
      def sessionId: Column[String] = column[String]("sessionId")
      def stamp: Column[DateTime] = column[DateTime]("stamp")

      def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String, DateTime)] = (id,textId,sessionId,stamp)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please add some context to your question as it's very hard to see what is not working (e.g. do you get compilation errors? Do you get exceptions?).

With respect to the question content, you should think of getting data from slick and translating it into JSON as two totally independent steps; in fact, there is nothing in slick that will help you in making JSON out of your case classes.

Given that, you will need to run your slick queries and get `case class` instances for your types out of them, e.g. you should get a `Seq[user]`. To convert that to JSON you should invoke `Json.toJson(myUserSeq)`. There is one thing that will probably get in your way for what I can see in your code: to have the `Format` correctly in scope you should put it in the companion object of your case class, e.g.:

```
case class User(...)

object User {
  implicit object format extends Format[User] { ... }
}
```

As a sideline, please be aware of the language's [coding standards](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/) if you want people to help you and your code to be readable (e.g. having lower-case class names in your code makes it very hard to follow).

Comment: I tried making a case class and then object but it didn't help. The web is full of guides for mixing up Slick versions from 1 to 3 so trying to google for help has been pretty horrid too. The error I get is:









`No Json serializer found for type slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple.TableQuery[assets.users]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
    Ok(Json.toJson(users))`

Comment: That error suggests that you are not running the query and you are trying to transform it to JSON rather than transforming the results; can you post the code where this error is raised and which version of slick you are using?

Comment: I've just run into the same issue and to solve it I used a similar approach (https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/blob/ec17d6299b2785d018704be9164088818e542c6c/play-scala-slick-example/app/models/Person.scala#L8). But immediately after `User.tupled` stops working and the only workaround I found is `(User.apply _).tupled`.

Comment: @sentenza I _think_ that that happens because you defined a companion object for `User`. It's one of the scala idiosynchrasies that defining the companion will make it so the `User` object is not seen as a function (despite having the `apply` method). That's one way to walk around this issue (i.e. explicitly refer to `apply` and force eta expansion by using the `(X.apply _)` syntax).